# ManualResetEventSlim Wait() doesn't work after Set() is done once

Tags: c#, multithreading

## What I want to do

I have some threads (e.g. Thread 1, Thread 2, Thread 3), and a queue of integers (e.g. 1, 2, 3). 
Every one second, I want to pause currently running thread, and pop from a queue, and run a thread that has the same id.

For example:

Let's say I have an array of thread,  and an integer that holds currently executing thread.

```
int[] myThread; //1, 2, 3
ManualResetEventSlim[] mre;  
executing = 1;
Queue myQueue; //2, 3

Time 0:01    //Thread 1 is running
Time 0:02    mre[executing].Wait();
             myQueue.Enqueue(executing);
             int nextThread = myQueue.Dequeue(); //say 2
             mre[nextThread].Set();
             executing = nextThread;
Time 0:03    //Same thing as at 0:02... 
Time 0:04    //Same above
Time 0:05    //Same above
```

and want outputs that look like this:

```
Time 0:01    I'm 1
             I'm 1
             I'm 1
Time 0:02    I'm 2 // thread 2 was selected
             I'm 2
             I'm 2
Time 0:03    I'm 3 // thread 3 was selected
             I'm 3
             I'm 3
Time 0:04    I'm 2 // thread 2 was selected
             I'm 2
             I'm 2
```

## What I'm doing

I have a main file that defines the action:

```
static void Main()
{
    CreateThread(Action, n);
}

public static void Action(int pid)
{
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i++)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("I'm "+ pid);
    }
}
```

## Problem

The problem is that once a thread is set with Set(), it cannot be blocked again with Wait(). Because of that, each thread just keeps executing the whole `Action` method until it's done.

and outputs look like this:

```
Time 0:01    I'm 1    //Only Thread 1 is unblocked
             I'm 1
             I'm 1    
Time 0:02    I'm 2    //Thread 2 was unblocked. 
             I'm 1    //Thread 1 is not blocked, so it keeps printing
             I'm 2
Time 0:03    I'm 3    //Thread 3 was unblocked.   
             I'm 1    //Thread 1 is not blocked
             I'm 2    //Thread 2 is not blocked either
```

I've been working on this for a while and am stuck. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: There are several things wrong, most of all you should use one AutoResetEvent from all threads which will allow one thread to proceed and automatically reset itself blocking others.

Comment: Please do not start the name of a class with "My", "myClass" is often used in examples for instances of a class to highlight the fact it is an instance!

Comment: @markmnl Thanks for the advice. I read that with AutoResetEvent, I can't specify which thread to unblock, so I had to use ManualResetEvent for each thread.

Comment: then use one ManualResetEvent, though your logic is also wrong - each thread will finish you loop in less than a millisecound.

Comment: @markmnl but can't I block a thread before the thread finish the loop? If I use one ManualResetEvent, Wait() will cause all threads to block, right? And Set() will unblock all threads?

Comment: This code does not make sense to me. You are calling `threads[pid].Start();` Yet your ThreadData class does not have the `Start` method. To start with you code won't even compile.

Comment: @zespri sorry I couldn't post all my codes so I put the short version of it. I edited the question to hide the deteails..

Comment: If you want to `wait()` inside `Action`, then why don't you try putting the code for it there?

Comment: @StevenLiekens The actual code is more complicated so I just put the simple example, but in the actual case, I need to be able to pause/resume threads..

Comment: Well you can't "pause" a thread in the sense that you can't freeze it from the outside. You'll need to call `mre.Wait()` somewhere inside the `Action` procedure. In your example, that would be at the start of the `for` loop. See my answer for inspiration.

Comment: @StevenLiekens Is it that once I use Set() for a thread, it can't be blocked again with WaitOne()?

Comment: Not unless you call `mre.Reset()` after `Set()`.

Comment: @StevenLiekens so do I use Set() and Reset() as a pair if I want to call WaitOne() later again?

Comment: Not really. In your example, you'd call `mre.Reset()` right before starting the next thread. This will cause the last thread to keep running until it hits `mre.Wait()`, at which point it will block until you once again call `mre.Set()`.

Comment: @StevenLiekens in that case, doesn't it run like `Th1, Th2, Th3` and done, instead of `Th1, Th2, Th3, Th1, Th2, Th3...`?

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you don't really need threads, since you always executing only a single thread at a time?

Comment: @zespri Yes, I want only one thread to be executed at a time, but I do need to control multiple threads to do so.

Comment: Can you briefly describe what your threads do?

Comment: It's too broad. You need to specify right tool for the task so it matters what they do.

Comment: @kabichan `Th1, Th2, Th3, done` is exactly what you are asking. The point is that the threads are not dead when the next thread starts. Instead, they block until the timer event unblocks them again. This would happen a couple of times until all threads run to completion, at which point your program should exit (I guess).

Comment: @zespri The problem is that I have to be able to pause/resume threads no matter what threads work on.

Comment: @StevenLiekens I won't be running the program only for 3 seconds, so it needs to keep running a thread at a time until .. say 1 minute passes or the program exits. I edited the question.

Comment: Again, you can't "freeze" a thread. You need to write your code so that it will block the thread it's in. If we could just freeze threads regardless of what code they are executing then we probably wouldn't need `*ResetEvent` classes in the first place.

Comment: However nothing will stop you from killing threads and then restarting them as you see fit. Please don't do that though.

Comment: @StevenLiekens hmm I thought there should be a way to block threads when I want to.. without killing them of course. If it's not feasible, that'll answer my question..

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I understand the problem, but I'd change `Action()` so that it takes an instance of `ThreadData`. You'll need it to check whether the MRE is set. If so, break out of the iteration and let the framework take care of cleaning up after the thread.

```
public static void Action(ThreadData threadData)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        if (threadData.Mre.IsSet)
        {
            break;
        }
        Trace.WriteLine("I'm " + threadData.Pid);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You might not realize it, but you're probably using the same instance of MRE for each thread. Each thread references the `mre` variable. Who is to say that the thread starts before you set `mre` to a new instance? Spoiler: it doesn't.